# How can one programmatically read the graph values from a Powerpoint presentation using Apache's POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint

I have a Powerpoint presentation with an graph which I want to access using Java and [Apache's POI](http://poi.apache.org/). When I edit the graph data using Powerpoint an Excel window opens with the values, I want to access these values from my Java application.

How does one access the values of the graph programmatically?

Comment: Can you not just [get the embedded resource](http://poi.apache.org/poifs/embeded.html) out, then open it with [Apache POI's HSSF spreadsheet code](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/) as normal?

Comment: @Gagravarr Your link shows how to do it for HSLF objects, but how do we go about doing the same for XSLF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first part we need to navigate to an `XSLFChart` object:

```
final String filename = "resources/fptbenchmark/Powerpoint Import.pptx";
final XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow(new FileInputStream(filename));

final XSLFSlide slide = ppt.getSlides()[5];
```

The slide contains different parts (`getRelations()`) one of which should
contain the `XSLFChart`:

```
final List<POIXMLDocumentPart> relations = slide.getRelations();
assert relations.size() == 3;

final XSLFChart xslfChart = (XSLFChart)relations.get(2);
```

When you examine the `xslfChart` variable in the debugger you will notice
that the field `CTChartImpl chart` shows the underlying XML data, which
might look like this:

```
<xml-fragment xmlns:c="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart"
xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main"
xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships">
<c:autoTitleDeleted val="0"/>
<c:plotArea>
  <c:scatterChart>
    <c:ser>
      <c:tx>
        <c:strRef>
          <c:f>Sheet1!$E$8</c:f>
          <c:strCache>
            <c:ptCount val="1"/>
            <c:pt idx="0">
              <c:v>y axis caption</c:v>
            </c:pt>
          </c:strCache>
        </c:strRef>
      </c:tx>
      <c:xVal>
        <c:numRef>
          <c:f>Sheet1!$A$9:$A$28</c:f>
          <c:numCache>
            <c:formatCode>General</c:formatCode>
            <c:ptCount val="20"/>
            <c:pt idx="0">
              <c:v>1200</c:v>
            </c:pt>
            <c:pt idx="1">
              <c:v>1600</c:v>
            </c:pt>
            <c:pt idx="2">
              <c:v>2000</c:v>
            </c:pt>
...
```

You can naviage this tree starting with the `CTChart`:

```
CTChart ctChart = xslfChart.getCTChart();
```

Since there is a `<c:plotArea>` tag, you call the associated member function to
access it:

```
CTPlotArea plotArea = ctChart.getPlotArea();
```

From there you should be able to navigate your way around

```
List<CTNumVal> ptList = plotArea.getScatterChartList().get(1)
    .getSerList().get(0)
    .getXVal()
    .getNumRef()
    .getNumCache()
    .getPtList();
```

Now you have access to the values:

```
ptList.get(0).getV();
```

**References**

- [ooxml-schemas-1.1.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/ooxml-schemas-1.1.jar)
- [Ecma-376](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm)