# How to refresh embedded content in a pptx using Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint, xslf

Dear all,

I'm working with Apache POI and I'm trying to automate some tasks with Powerpoint reports. More precisely, I would like to update the data inside a .pptx presentation from code, including embedded Excel spreadsheets (displayed as table).

So far, I've managed to update the embedded spreadsheet itself, but the pptx presentation is not "refreshed": when I open the file, the old value is visible, but the new value shows up when I double-click on the grid (entering "edit" mode).

According to Gagravarr's comment this post [Unable to see Apache POI updated data value in BarChart in pptx without editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17890549/unable-to-see-apache-poi-updated-data-value-in-barchart-in-pptx-without-editing), this behavior is expected: the underlying file is indeed updated, but the pre-rendered version remains.

As a result, I would like to "refresh" the pre-rendered version: do you know how I can do that with Apache POI? (or at least "zap" this pre-rendered version and hope that Powerpoint will re-render it when I open the slideshow).

I'm not familiar with POI users list archives, so I'm sorry if the answer was there somewhere. Thanks a lot, and best regards!

Here is my current code:

```java
// Open SlideShow
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFilePath);
XMLSlideShow slideShow = new XMLSlideShow(fileInputStream);
fileInputStream.close();


// Get PackagePart (shortened version)
PackagePart excelEmbedding = slideshow.getAllEmbedds().get(3);


// Update underlying spreadsheet (shortened version)
InputStream is = excelEmbedding.getInputStream();
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(is);    

XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(1);
XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(3);
cell.setCellValue("TEST");

OutputStream os = excelEmbedding.getOutputStream();
workbook.write(os);
os.close();
workbook.close();


// Save changes
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFilePath);
slideShow.write(fileOutputStream);
fileOutputStream.close();
```